# Share Preference Not store Data, and Getting Error in launch file, if using setMockInitialValues then value is reset

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have using share preference for store login data. and it's working fine but when i update flutter sdk and New version of Share preference which ^0.5.6. this is created issue. lunch file not display anything and App is stuck in launch mode Getting error like  "**Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)**".

I have check solution for Same and I get  "**SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues ({})**" to use and  I used this then share preference clear data everytime.

Comment: Maybe do flutter clean

Comment: @HussnainHaidar i do this thing many times not working

Comment: @Arti did you solve this issue ?